# prelink: <lib*> does not have .gnu.prelink_undo section and cannot open ELF file: no error in pyintsller

Tags: python, pyinstaller, prelink

I have pyinstaller script with LD_LIBRARY_PATH where following binary are there in system.

- libldap_r-2.4.so.2
- libpq.so.5
- libpython2.7.so.1.0

I am running code like:

python pyinstaller.py my_script

prelink -u lib*

after the execution for prelink I am getting error like:

prelink: cannot open ELF file: no error

prelink: libldap_r-2.4.so.2 does not have .gnu.prelink_undo section

prelink: libpq.so.5 does not have .gnu.prelink_undo section

prelink: libpython2.7.so.1.0 does not have .gnu.prelink_undo section

can somebody help me to solve this?